# Deleting specific members of an array javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I'm making a simple html5 Canvas game for educational purposes. I have an array which holds all of the separate prototypes of the same enemy object. When the enemy goes off the screen or perhaps is killed by player, I want to be able to despawn it from within the object by deleting it altogether from the array. I'll probably create new instances of the enemy by pushing a new object to the array with some pseudo-random properties.

I apologize for not providing code, if you'd like to see anything specific just ask.

Comment: Add code, or you'll get downvoted before you reach the end of this sentence. Just a tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), which takes two argumets `index, howMany` to remove elements from an array, starting at the specified `index`

Heres a basic [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/njngc/)

```
var players = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
players.splice (3,1); //remove 1 element beginning at index 3
console.log (players) // [1,2,3,5,6]
```

As you see player 4 *(which is at index 3 in players*) got removed

Comment: How do I figure out where any one object is indexed in the array from within that object?

Comment: @AlexKrokos `players.indexOf (player)`

Comment: Every element of the array is a prototype of the same object, how can I use indexOf if theyr'e all the same?

Comment: @AlexKrokos What do you mean by "Every element of the array is a prototype of the same object" ? An object has only one prototype, multiple objects can have the same prototype, but not the other way round. Do you mean every element has the same prototype? / is an instance of player ?